# How do I hide the SSID of an Android phone?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I sometimes use my phone as an ad-hoc WiFi network, however there is no option in the settings to hide its SSID. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you use the "Wi-Fi hotspot" feature to make a Wi-Fi network? That's **not** what an ad-hoc network is.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide AP SSID (stop SSID broadcasting or beaconing) through Android API.

SSID hiding depends on the kernel/WiFi-driver that you have on your phone. Only a few drivers (devices) support this feature. Also, a few drivers support monitor mode. Vendor-drivers have closed source which makes it difficult to add these features to them. See [bcmon](https://code.google.com/p/bcmon/) project for example.

Android API allows you to connect to the network with specific SSID (it may be hidden) programmatically. You should know network SSID and password (see this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html#hiddenSSID) about `WifiConfiguration` class and `hiddenSSID`, this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) about `WifiManager` class, and these Stack Overflow answers: [programmatically create WiFi Configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android), [connect to a specific WiFi network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)).